# Snapchat clone: How do I secure pre-downloaded notifications so that they cannot be opened outside of the app?

Tags: cryptography, drm

Say I'm making a snapchat clone app for Android and iOS. Let's say that I get a snapchat from Baz. I want to pre-download the audio for this snapchat. However, as the developer, I want to secure this audio from being viewable outside of the app.

I've been thinking of encrypting it using AES with an IV and key that are both generated from a pseudo-random function that takes the user's unique ID as input. However, if an attacker found out that this was the way we encrypt our files, and had access to our PRF, he would easily be able to decrypt it and store it permanently. The thing is, I don't have enough background in cryptography or android programming to tell if that's really a concern or not. The attacker has to learn a lot about our cipher in order to break it, but he could gain pretty much all of that from looking at the unobfuscated source of our app.

Is my suggested approach cryptographically secure? What other, better or simpler approaches could I take to solving this problem?